# glfwInit() fails. What should I do?

Tags: c++, opengl, cygwin, x11, glfw

So, I can't create any windows because `glfwInit()` fails.

Here's my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(DuperTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
add_subdirectory(glfw-3.2.1)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(DuperTest ${SOURCE_FILES})

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(DuperTest glfw)
target_link_libraries(DuperTest ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
```

And my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main()
{
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        std::cout << "glfwInit" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And I'm absolutely lost. How do I fix it?

**UPDATE:**

added error callback. It returned this message:

```
"X11: The DISPLAY environment variable is missing"
```

Comment: On a sidenote: Calling `glfwTerminate` manually is not required since it is called automatically by [glfwInit](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__init.html#ga317aac130a235ab08c6db0834907d85e) on failure.

Comment: Also, it usually `glfwInit` failing has something to do with a lower level issue, so you should give us more details about your system, installed drivers etc.

Comment: @BenSteffan updated.

Comment: Interesting that the variable is not defined, try setting it to `:0.0` as per https://askubuntu.com/questions/432255/what-is-display-environment-variable/432257

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson but I'm working on Windows...

Comment: @user1496491: Could it be, that you're working in a Cygwin environment? If so, that's your problem right there. Use MinGW/MSys2 instead.

Comment: oh god, you right! It worked! But why?

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue for days and was unable to find anything helpful online. I was finally able to discover the problem: The `glfw-wayland` package installed while I was using the X11 system. Uninstalling the wayland package and installing `glfw-x11` successfully resolved GLFW from being unable to initialize.

The question was asked over half a decade ago, but I still answer in the hopes that it might save somebody from days of being blocked.