# GLFW error #65544 "Failed to initialize GLFW"

Tags: c++, ubuntu, glfw

here's my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(void){

    GLFWwindow* window;

    if(!glfwInit()){
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLFW!" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if(!window){
        glfwTerminate();
        std:: cout << "Failed to initialize Window!" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

I successfully linked it and compile, but I'm having a runtime error
it says that glfw failed to initialize.I tried to use glfw in C but this error shows

```bash
Wayland: Failed to connect to display
The GLFW library is not initialized
main: ./src/posix_thread.c:64: _glfwPlatformGetTls: Assertion `tls->posix.allocated == GLFW_TRUE' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

. I'm using popOS 22.04 LTS, I'm new to c++ and glfw pls help me fix this problem

Comment: just as i said I'm new to this so i thought it might fix the problem

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43431686/glfwinit-fails-what-should-i-do

Answer (score 0):

### The Problem

The reason why you are getting these errors is because the glfw framework doesn't get the opportunity to be initialized before being used to create the window. Because of this, glfw is returning the error message given.

```
Wayland: Failed to connect to display
The GLFW library is not initialized
main: ./src/posix_thread.c:64: _glfwPlatformGetTls: Assertion `tls-posix.allocated == GLFW_TRUE' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

### The Solution

To fix this problem, try moving the code segment

```cpp
if(!glfwInit()){
    std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLFW!" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
```

Above the `GLFWwindow* window` declaration at the beginning of the main function.

### Quick Tip

Try to declare and initialize the window in one line like so: `GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "GLFW WINDOW", NULL, NULL)`
It's much easier to read and overall helps to reduce the number of lines of code.